# How do i place seprate databinding for inputext populated through traversing list in li tag in razor components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-components

I am dynamically displaying unordered list in razor components by looping a list. Every li in ul has a inputText field binded with a variable and a button but on clicking a button every inputText shows the same text input in any of the inputtext.

```
@page "/questions"

<ul>
    @foreach(var item in list)
    {
        <li>@item <input bind="@inputText"/><button onclick="@Display">Display</button></li>
    }

</ul>



@functions{
    List<string> list = new List<string>()
    {
        "Hello",
        "World"
    };

    string inputText = "";


    void Display()
    {
        //item + inputText
    }


}
```

I want separate binding for every populated inputText.

Comment: Do you want your inputs to have the values contained in the list you are looping through?

Comment: No, what i want is to get the value from the input but the problem is a soon as i enter something in any of the input  it's get visible on every input i'm displaying by looping